# Changing a draggable element's content while dragging and hovering over a certain div using jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, html, draggable

I'm trying to do two fairly simple tasks.

1. I simply want a draggable image to change to a different image when its being dragged, and goes back to normal when I let go. I read about the Helper option in the jQuery UI website but this doesnt make the original image disappear when I start to drag. I want the original draggable image to change into a new one while its being dragged. and return to what it was before when I let go.
2. What I want to do is to have the draggable object (an image) change to a different image when I drag it above a certain div (but not dropping it, still dragging).

So let say I have a square Div and Image1 is draggable. I want Image1 to become Image2 when i drag it over the square Div.

Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery UI? Thanks in advance.

An alternative would be to change the class of the div when the drag happens.

Something like this for example, if I can change class of the div the moment the draggable gets dragged into class2 and when it mouse over a div to class3 that'd help alot, thanks:

```
<style>

.class1{
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.class2{
   width:75px;
   height:75px;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.class3{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   border:1px solid black;
}

.droppable {
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
   border:1px red;
}

</style>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#drag-container" ).draggable({ revert: true });
});
<script>

<div id="drag-container" class="class1">
   <p>Drag Box</p>
</div>

<div class="droppable">
   <p>Drop Area</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle to let kids play

Comment: Sorry, heres a code snippet example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took a little "playing" around, but I think I've got what you're after.

Played with this a bit more, and seeing as how you're using droppable as well as draggable you can use this simplified method.

<kbd>**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ztV2q/5/)**</kbd>

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    helper: "original",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").html('<img src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png">');
    },
    revert: function (x) {
        if (!x) {
            $("#draggable").html('<img src="http://myrrix.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/stackoverflow.png">');
            return true;
        }
    }
});

$('.box').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").html('<img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png">');
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").html('<img src="http://blog.grio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/stackoverflow.png">');
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $("#draggable").html('<img src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png">');
    }
});
```

Other Methods
**<kbd>[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ztV2q/1/)</kbd>**
<kbd>**[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ztV2q/2/)**</kbd>
<kbd>**[Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/ztV2q/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: @yanZ263 Is this not what you were after?

Comment: I tried that code snippet to see the effect. Its somewhat what Im trying to get, but I noticed the image dont change after it lands in the droppable box.

In a nutshell I basically need 3 states for my draggable object. One for neutral, one for when its dragged, and one for when it hits the droppable box.

Thanks for this though, its helping me figure this out.

Comment: @YanZ263 for the drop element you have to add another event. like so
drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }

Comment: Oh I just noticed the code has been edited, I must've grabbed the one prior to the edit, leme try, thanks!

Comment: The Third one is perfect! Except for one little thing.

The way you have it now, it only goes into image 2 when I go over the drop box, and becomes Image 3 when I let go. What I wanted was for it to become Image2 the moment its being dragged around anywhere, and become image 3 when its dragged over the dropbox (as well as when I drop it in).

Regardless this helps me alot, you're awesome, thanks alot :D

Comment: Hi, I have one last question concerning the third example. I played around with the code and got what I wanted where the image change to image2 the moment I start dragging. However after I let go and it reverts back to its original position, it still remains as image 2. Is there a way to make it so it reverts back to Image1 when I let go of the drag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ztV2q/4/

Pretty much what you had for the third example, but I switched the image URLs around to get the effect I wanted. All I basically need now is for the image to go back to the default image after I let go of it without dropping it into the box.

Comment: @YanZ263 see last update, I was able to simplify it quite a bit

Comment: Thank you so much!! I wish I could rep up you but it wont let me cause I dont have 15 reps. I'll be sure to do so once I do. Thanks again!